# Extjs 3.4 How to force a combobox to reload its dropdown

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

So I have a combobox that reloads its store upon expansion. I am able to get the store updated but I can't seem to get the combobox to display the new info in the store. It keeps on showing the old information. I have used almost every method and have been fooling around for hours. I am also being forced to use extjs 3.4.

General idea of my code:

```
codeFilterCombo = new Ext.form.ComboBox ({
    id: 'filterByFlagField',
    allowBlank: true,
    editable: false,
    lazyRender: true,
    width: 220,
    name: 'flagFilterCombo',
    displayField: 'msg',
    valueField: 'icon',
    hiddenValue: 'icon',
    hiddenId:'FlagFilterHidden',
    hiddenName: 'FlagFilter',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    mode: 'local',
    tpl: resultTpl,
    listeners: {
        expand: function() {
            this.store.removeAll();
            var data = getAvailableFlags();
            this.store.loadData(data);
            this.show();
        }
    }        
});
```

Comment: Do you actually see the items of the store updated in the console? Do you actually see the gif of loading in the combo?

Comment: Yes, I can see the items in the store updated in the console. I step through the process and look and the store is how its supposed to be. Getting the combobox to then refresh with that information seems to be where im failing. No, I do not see a loading gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really old question, but maybe it will still help someone. I think you're approaching this wrong. If you want your store to reload every time the combobox is opened, you're supposed to delete lastQuery.

From the documentation:

```
var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    ...
    mode: 'remote',
    ...
    listeners: {
        // delete the previous query in the beforequery event or set
        // combo.lastQuery = null (this will reload the store the next time     it expands)
        beforequery: function(qe){
            delete qe.combo.lastQuery;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: to be fair...that wasn't in the documentation when I wrote this question ;)

Answer (score -1):

I would try changing mode:local to remote.

Comment: mode:remote would only mean that im getting my data remotely. Which I am not. However, out of pure morbid curiosity I changed the setting and it did not help. Same result.